# Emacs visual-line-mode in -nw mode - is it possible?

Tags: terminal, emacs

Emacs have largely switched to visual-line-mode as default, but what do I use if I am working in -nw mode? Visual-line-mode is not working, and longlines-mode is branded as obsolete.

Comment: What makes you think `visual-line-mode` doesn't work in `-nw`?

Comment: emacs -nw; MacOS default terminal or iTerm2.

in .emacs:

(global-visual-line-mode 1)

Response on starting emacs -nw:

An error has occurred while loading `/Users/[myname]/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: global-visual-line-mode

I have to use:

(if window-system
(global-visual-line-mode 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `-nw`: it's that you're not using the same Emacs in the two cases.  When using `-nw` you're starting Emacs from the command line, most likely running MacOS's builtin `/usr/bin/emacs` (which is a dinosaur) instead of running the Emacs you installed yourself.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand that the "dinosaur" does indeed have no idea of visual-line-mode. No problem in general, it is that in some rare cases all what is available is the default version (in the case of re-installing the system of the fly due to some malfunction, for example).

Comment: I recommend you complain to Apple about it (or upgrade to something like Debian)